# How to copy contents of a (large) vim file to the OSX system clipboard to paste in other apps?

Tags: osx, vim, clipboard

I like to use vim to edit other (non-programming languages) stuff. So I paste the content into vim and make the changes.

How can I copy *all* of the text back into the primary clipboard for pasting?

Note that I use iTerm2 and the ability to use * isn't there as it is with the basic osx terminal app.

I don't want to copy to a vim internal register (such as the `y` yank command), I want to copy to the system clipboard.

Also, I want the contents of the whole file, including the content which is off-screen?

The <kbd>alt</kbd>-left-click-drag with mouse doesn't work.

Comment: on OSX `:%w !pbcopy`

Comment: I got `/bin/bash: pbcopy: command not found`

Comment: However +1 as it led me to an answer (below).  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this in a better way than my other answer:

First of all get the new vim with

```
brew install vim
```

and then do

```
vim --version
```

Make sure it is 7.4+  Note that if you do vi --version you may that vi is at 7.3

Now make vi use that newer vim

```
alias vi=vim
```

and add that alias to your .bash_aliases file (or wherever you put aliases)

Finally add

```
set clipboard=unnamed
```

to your `.vimrc` (not `.bashrc`!)

Start a new shell and it should work.

Answer (score 4):

I'm sure this is a duplicate but:

```
gg"*yG
```

`gg` go to the first line
`"*y` start a yank to the system clipboard "register"
`G` move to the end of the file (you will see how many lines were yanked)

Comment: @MichaelDurrant talking in ALL CAPS doesn't make you right. The `*` and `+` buffers *are* for interfacing with the system clipboard. See http://vi.stackexchange.com/a/96/205

Comment: This simply didn't work for me.

Comment: @MichaelDurrant Hmm. OSX, isn't it? Try the `+` register (`gg"+yG`).

Comment: Thanks muru, Looks like my version of bash doesn't this functionality.  I am on Yosemite 10.10.4

Answer (score 1):

This alternative option using a `:` command worked for me:

```
:1,$!pbcopy
```

This is useful for referring to line numbers, etc without having to navigate and highlight the area.